# Abort execution during OMNET simulation

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++

I have 4 nodes in my simulation, in the code i check on a **flag**.

If it is become true during the run of ***any node*** then >> i want to stop the execution for ***all the nodes*** and go to execute finish method for ***each node.***

I try to do as following but it doesn't call finish method!

```
if(flag == true)
{ finish();
 abort();
}
```

How i can do it?
Thanks,

Comment: You have not shown enough code for this question to be answerable. Please show enough code for the problem to be demonstrable. Based just on those three lines however, it is clear that `abort()` will be called regardless of whether `(flag == true)` - is this intended?

Comment: I edit it, this is just as pseudo code that i want to check a flag then make action if its true .

Comment: Ok, but you haven't addressed the main point, which is that the question is unanswerable in it's current form. In your current code example, `finish` **will** be called if `(flag == true)`. Either the code is never reached, or `(flag == false)`, or `finish` is being called and just isn't producing the side effects you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this command?
endSimulation();

It ends the simulation, however I am not sure if it runs finish method or not..

Comment: It does call finish and cleanly exits the simulation